# C# Blazor pass type param to component using a typename supplied as string

Tags: blazor, type-parameter

I want to pass a type parameter to a Blazor component by supplying it from a list of types.

Component ("TextDataGrid.razor"):

```cs
    @typeparam TData where TData : ITextData, new()

    <!-- some html -->

    @code {
    // ...
    }
```

Types:

```cs
    namespace MyApp.Shared.Models
    {
        public interface ITextData
        {
            public Guid ID { get; set; }
            public string Value { get; set; }
        }

        public class TextData : ITextData 
        {
            public TextData() { }
            public Guid ID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
            public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        }

        public partial class BusinessUnitNames : TextData { }
        public partial class ProductNames : TextData { }
    }
```

Calling component:

```cs
    @for (int i = 0; i < TextDataTypeNames.Length; i++)
    {
       <TextDataGrid TData=@Type.GetType(TextDataTypeNames[i]) />
    }

    @code {
        readonly string[] TextDataTypeNames =  
        {
            "MyApp.Shared.Models.BusinessUnitNames", 
            "MyApp.Shared.Models.ProductNames"
        }
    }
```

Also not working is this:

```cs
    @for (int i = 0; i < TextDataTypeNames.Length; i++)
    {
       <TextDataGrid TData=@TextDataType(i) />
    }

    @code {
        Type TextDataType(int i)
        {
            return Type.GetType(TextDataTypeNames[i]);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error message at "TData=@TextDataType":

[image: TextDataType error messages]

Note: Omitting "@" at the function calls doesn't help either.

The generated code looks like this:

```
__builder5.AddAttribute(37, "ContentTemplate", (RenderFragment)((__builder6) => {
    __builder6.OpenComponent<TextDataGrid<Type.GetType(TextDataTypeName(i))>>(38);
    ...
    }
```

The second line has a nested type parameter. The inner one is not a type, but a call to Type.GetType. This probably cannot work. The problem is that the actual TextDataGrid code is created at compile time, while the method I am using to provide the type parameter is executed at runtime.

Is there a way to work around this?